# How to recover/restore lost session in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, restore, session, recovery

So I signed out of one of my google accounts which had all my tabs and it immediately closed my session and replaced it with the session from my other account. Now the tabs from my original account are gone and I have no idea how to get them back.

Does anyone know where to find session buddy data?

I found a sessions folder  AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sessions dated Jan 05 how do I open the tabs_231489324 file in chrome?

[image]

As mentioned these files are not images I'm not sure what they are but they are in the sessions folder so I thought they might contain the session information.

Comment: @Ramhound  I have sessions (or files named session) in my chrome folder in my google chrome appdata folder how do I load the session?

Comment: @Ramhound  I'm not entirely sure  https://drive.google.com/file/d/19_tNz0BWdGQEDdmY35u0cON7RcLPNZuL/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8RUGaT9tJH5QpJSqS9jMp7E5bfoBpFx/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTNTqlknrei0-NRhPPJagJwJQ-4r05nV/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o0zJQ55I4jTKMfqXj8HiBeHpvQbpMurl/view?usp=sharing
but they're just files that say session   btw is there a way to search for saved sessions within  the appdata folder in google chrome?

Comment: @Ramhound  Their not images I'm not sure what they are but they're named session**** by google chrome and in  the User Data\Snapshots\108.0.5359.126\Profile 10\Sessions  folder so idk I thought they were sessions  incidently do you know where I might be able to find old sessions?

Comment: @Ramhound  are you unable to download the files or are you unable to open them?  As mentioned I'm not sure what kind of file this is I just found it in my google chrome appdata folder under sessions so I thought it might be relevant but I have no idea if it actually is.  I added a picture in an answer below because I cannot edit my post.

Comment: @Ramhound  you should be able to see a screenshot in the answer below

Comment: @Ramhound  but is it possible to recover a session from chromes files?

Comment: @Ramhound   but they're dated Jan 06